# Group list of elements according to list of identifiers

Tags: python, list, grouping

I have the following list:

```
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

And I want to group the elements according to the id number in this list:

```
[2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0]
```

so I get:

```
[[3, 4, 5, 9], [2, 6, 7], [1, 8]]
```

Thanks

Comment: check `zip` function and how it works.

Comment: voting to close the questions.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your first list is unique. you can create a dictionary and sort based on key.
If your python version is 2.* then use `sorted(dictA.iteritems())` instead of `sorted(dictA.items())`

```
keys = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
values = [2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0]
dictA = dict(zip(keys, values))
res = {}

for key, value in sorted(dictA.items()):
    res.setdefault(value, []).append(key)
print(res)
```

**Edit 1:** To sort the dictionary and to get dictionary values

```
import collections
od = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(res.items()))
list(od.values())
```

You must do some work arounds here. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but this generates a dictionary and I need a list of lists

Comment: you can use this to get in list format `list(res.values())`

Answer (score 0):

This generates a list of list of the desired output

```
values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
keys = [2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0]

nKeys = len(set(keys))

result = [ [] for i in range(nKeys)]

for kid, vid in zip(keys, values):
    result[kid].append(vid)
```